# Отобразить журналы, количество выпусков которых за текущий год меньше среднего количества выпуска журналов

Tags: sql

Возникла проблема с запросом в SQL SERVER.
Необходимо создать запрос "Отобразить журналы, количество выпусков которых за текущий год меньше среднего количества выпуска журналов".
Как это можно реализовать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Название,Avg(Номер_выпуска) as кол_за_последний_год,(Select Avg(Номер_выпуска) From Выпуски_журналов) as среднее_кол_выпусков
From Выпуски_журналов, Журналы
where (Журналы.id_журнала = Выпуски_журналов.id_журнала) and Year(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)=Год 
Group by Название
having Avg(Номер_выпуска) < (Select Avg(Номер_выпуска) From Выпуски_журналов)
```

Comment: Если кому нужно